# Use AJAX/JSON to pass an array of objects to PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, object

I need to pass a Javascript array of objects to PHP. Found about 3 solutions on the internet, but none of them worked for me. The array looks like this (in Chrome dev console):

[image]

And my current AJAX call looks like this:

```
function consolidate() {
        var studentsstring = JSON.stringify(students);
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",  
             url: "writefile.php",
             dataType: "json", 
             data: {students: students},
             success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
             }
        });
    }
```

And the PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
print($_POST['students']);
?>
```

Currently, when I hit the "consolidate" button, nothing happens. No alert is shown. Chrome dev reports no errors in the code.

Comment: please show the HTML for the button, how it fires the "consolidate" function. Can you verify that the "consolidate" function is actually called by putting an alert on the first line? That would help to narrow down the problem. You can also watch the Network tab in the browser to see if the ajax request is sent, and what (if anything) comes back.

Comment: Try to manually run `consolidate()`in the console. The click event associated with your button might not work.

Comment: `var studentsstring = JSON.stringify(students);` also appears to be redundant.

Comment: "nothing happens" — Are you sure? What do the developer tools in your browser say? Are any errors reported on the Console? Do you see the request in the Network tab? Does it get a response? Are the HTTP status codes what you expect?

Comment: Check network tab as @Quentin said and do echo json_encode($_POST['students']); because your ajax waits for json response

Comment: from where you get the variable " students " in the line  var studentsstring = JSON.stringify(students);

Comment: We need to see the bigger picture, as there could be any number of issues, of the top of my head, the function is never called, `students` is out of scope, server sends a non 200 header.

Comment: Also, for SO use in general, make sure you are available to answer comments pretty much immediately, because all these commentators will likely have completely forgotten your question exists in 10 minutes.

Comment: `print($_POST['students']);` to `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: While passing data to php use "studentsstring".
ie data: {students: studentsstring}

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I'm dumb. Too many hours of coding. The line should have been:

```
data: {students: studentsstring},
```

and now it works. Thanks all.